# WebView inside application?

Tags: android, web-applications

So I have a WebView inside of a LinearLayout with an EditText Box and a Button to make the application search for the web. When I click go on my button it takes me to the stock android browser. how do I make It so that it stays within my WebView when I click go?
here is my layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
      <EditText
       android:id="@+id/web_address"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="http://"/>

      <Button
       android:id="@+id/go"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/go"
       android:gravity="right"/>

 <WebView
     android:id="@+id/webview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

here is my source:

```
    package straightapp.com.Browser;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

     public class Browser extends Activity {
 WebView mWebView;
 Button button;
 EditText text;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.straightapp.com");

        text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.web_address);
        button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.go);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    openBrowser();

   }
        });
        text.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                            openBrowser();
                            return true;
                    }

                    return false;
            }
            });
    }

    public void openBrowser(){
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(text.getText().toString());
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise, you can try following change:

```
public void openBrowser(){
    //Ensure that URL entered is a valid one
    mWebView.loadUrl(text.getText().toString());
}
```

Comment: That just took me to the stock browser.

Comment: @Christian: It may be the Web page you are trying to load performs a redirect. Redirects and clicks-on-links in a `WebView`, by default, open into the user's default browser. You can use a `WebViewClient` and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` to change this behavior.

Comment: @CommnsWare: I am sorry, I am a bit of a noobie. were would I put these?

Comment: @TheCottonSilk: When I added setContentView(mWebView); the program just closed when I clicked the go button. I did add mWebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview); but it still force closed.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I did not see setContentView() call in onCreate(). Which test URL you are trying to load?

Comment: @CommonsWare and TheCottonSilk: Okay I was Wrong the mWebView.loadUrl(text.getText().toString()); did work and I am sorry for all the extra trouble thank you two very much.

Answer (score 2):

> When I click go on my button it takes me to the stock android browser.

That's because that is what you told Android to do. `startActivity()` starts an activity.

> how do I make It so that it stays within my WebView when I click go?

Call `loadUrl()` on your `WebView` instead of calling `startActivity()`.

Comment: so insted of: public void openBrowser(){
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(text.getText().toString());
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
        startActivity(intent);

Comment: i would have:public void openBrowser(){
        Uri uri=Uri.parse(text.getText().toString());
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
        loadUrl(intent);

Comment: @Christian: No. That will not even compile. See @TheCottonSilk's answer.

Comment: Right I found that out when I tried it. so  was making sure that isn't what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Change your xml file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".Browser"> <!--Just add this line -->
      <EditText
       android:id="@+id/web_address"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="http://"/>

      <Button
       android:id="@+id/go"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="@drawable/go"
       android:gravity="right"/>

 <WebView
     android:id="@+id/webview"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

First declare the webview and progressbar

```
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Copy and paste this code below onCreate method

```
   public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```